# jQuery to HTML interface - How can you fix intermittent function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have code taken straight from W3schools - I was learning about basic JS/HTML forms. All I wanted to do was pull data from two text field inputs and multiply them together.

The code I found functions intermittently, and I can see no rhyme or reason to why. When it does not work, it does not return "NaN" - it seemingly just does nothing.

**NOTE:** **I have wrapped the .js in a "$(document).ready(function()..."**

Here's the full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
    2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
    <input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
</form>
<p>The Result is: <br>
    <span id = "result"></span>
</p>

<script src="tb2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function multiplyBy()
    {
            num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
    }
 
    function divideBy() 
    { 
            num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
    }
});
```

Earlier it worked, then I changed some variable names and it broke. Troubleshooting this, I changed:

```
"<script src="https://www.     .com/tb2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
</body>"
```

to:

```
<script src="tb2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

**That fixed it again.** Trying to understand the issue, I tried another browser (NetSurfer) - the code that *is presently running in Chrome didn't work there.*

I've slightly abridged the story and steps taken (I've been fiddling with this and researching for 6 hours,) but I want to know what is causing this erratic function - any help will be much appreciated.

*Edit:
When I saw it "doesn't work," I mean when I click the button input, the output field remains unchanged.
It's working again right now so I have no console errors to report.

***Edit: It's a problem with loading jQuery specifically. I didn't realize the code I sent y'all was vanilla JS until somebody pointed it out. I changed the "document.getElementByID" to "$" and it broke immediately.**
Not sure why jQuery won't load, I've tried three different servers.. I have the jQuery src at the beginning of my  section.

Comment: `NOTE: I have wrapped the .js in a "$(document).ready(function()..."` it's not necessary to put the divideBy/multiplyBy functions inside document.ready.  What is the problem that you see?  Any errors in the console?

Comment: When you say "it does not work" - what exactly does that mean? Maybe a look into the browser console can provide further clues as to _what_ has gone wrong.

Comment: In general I can only second the post by @PateeGutee: 1. you do not really need jQuery here 2. you don't need to place the function definitions into a block that is executed after the page has loaded.

Comment: Updated my code answer to use jquery instead of vanilla js.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some minor updates to your code:

*Update: Code updated to use jquery.*

html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./tb2.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
    2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
    <input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
    <p>The Result is: <span id="result"></span></p>
</body>
```

tb2.js:

```
function multiplyBy()
{
    num1 = $('#firstNumber').val();
    num2 = $('#secondNumber').val();
    $('#result').html(num1 * num2);
}

function divideBy() 
{ 
    num1 = $('#firstNumber').val();
    num2 = $('#secondNumber').val();
    $('#result').html(num1 / num2);
}
```

There's no need to include jquery since you are using vanilla javascript code in tb2.js. Don't put your multiply and divide function inside $(document).ready() since the calculations are done on click button events not on page ready event.

Update: jquery added back since the post was edited asking for jquery.

Comment: As @PateeGutee mentioned: the functions `multiplyBy()` and `divideBy()` will be triggered by a click event. Therefore it is not critical _when_ they are defined. In this context it does also not matter whether the script is included into the page itself or loaded from an external source (with `<script src="..."></script>`). In the above snippet I chose the (only possible in SO) way of including the script into the page.

Comment: When I went to bed, it was working. 
Now it isn't. I implemented your changes/suggestions, and it's still not working.

Comment: @RasaCarta Can you add an "Update" section at the bottom of your post showing your updated code? If your code is exactly identical to what was suggested here, it should work fine. Tips: keep saving the file after updating, do an "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in your browser after saving your files.